# lua math.randomseed returns nothing

Tags: lua

I have the following code:

```
   APP.logevent('ostime:'..os.time())
   APP.logevent('random:'..math.random())
   APP.logevent(math.randomseed(os.time()))
```

When i check my logs, this is what I get:

```
Tue Feb  5 11:49:53 2013: ostime:1360082993
Tue Feb  5 11:49:53 2013: random:0.84018771715471
Tue Feb  5 11:49:53 2013: 
machinename:/usr/share/ajj#
```

I'm not getting any error messages.... 
Can you tell me why the call to randomeseed() is failing?
I've also tried replacing the call to "os.time()" in the randomseed with a number... and that doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> lua math.randomseed returns nothing

It's not supposed to. Lua functions are not required to return a values, and there's no real reason for randomseed to return anything.

> Can you tell me why the call to randomeseed() is failing?

It's not.

EDIT:

> I thought it would create a random number for me.

That's what [`math.random`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.random) does. [`randomseed`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.randomseed) *seeds* the random number generator, which is to say it sets an initial value that the pseudorandom number generator uses to find the next pseudorandom value. For a given seed (including the default seed, i.e. you never call `randomseed`), you'll get the same list of pseudorandom values back every time.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the help, but I think you could spare us the obscenities.  and for the record, many of us do try to do our own homework and read before posting.  The docs i happened to read didn't provide me with all the info i needed to understand. http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=math.randomseed.

Comment: your first stop for any issue with the standard libs for a language should be to go directly to the documentation: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/

gammon posts some good stuff, but it definitely isn't on par with the reference manual